# Port 443 is not opening in ubuntu

Tags: firewall, ssl, openssl

I have been trying to install ssl certificate. For that I need to open the port 443.

But somehow its not opening. I already enables it on firewall.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the list of port which are open now

[image: screenshot]

Every time I try to connect got this

```
connect : Connection refused
connect :errno=111
```

Note : I don't have much knowledge about ubuntu. So I except brief answers regarding my problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two primary points that you'll need to look into:

1. Port 443 does not need to be open to do the installing of an SSL certificate. The SSL certificate (of a website I'm assuming since you're talking about port 443) should be already created and available to the web service being used on the server.
2. You need a web service running (e.g. Apache or Nginx) and configured to listen on port 443. Opening the port on the firewall just makes it so that the service listening on that port can be reached externally.

Comment: apache has been running on the server.So how can i configure port 443